# Sum of all deviations/squared deviations in a set?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am really stumped on this question on my homework:

---

The fuel efficiency (in miles per gallon) of 12 small utility trucks measured were recorded as follows:
`21 | 24 | 24 | 26 | 14 | 23 | 25 | 33 | 24 | 22 | 25 | 22`

For this sample, calculate the following measures:

- Sum of all deviations (round to whole number)
- Sum of all squared deviations (round to nearest hundredth)

---

I do have the answers to both questions, they are `0` and `202.90`, respectively, however I don't understand how such answers are retrieved. Sadly, my teacher does not include formulas for us to use.

If anyone can help explain how to solve for both of these I would really appreciate it!

Comment: The first thing you are supposed to calculate, is the average of the numbers. I get it to be $23.58333\ldots$. Then the "deviation" is the difference of the values and the average. However, the sum of squared deviations that I get with this average is much higher than $202.90$, so something seems off ...

Comment: Worth noting:  the sum of the deviations of any sample is $0$...that's what "mean" means, really  @MattiP.  For what it's worth, I get $202.92$ as $\sum(X-\overline X)^2$.

Comment: It might be worth explaining a bit of intuition behind such a task. You can see just by looking at the data points, that they all vary, right? But by how much? One way to measure it, would be for each data point, calculate how far away it is from the mean. Since some points will be smaller than the mean (resulting in a negative number), you can square the difference i.e. $(data point - mean)^2$ to preserve its "value" when combined with others later during summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the mean($\bar X$) fuel efficiency, which comes to $23.583333$
Then the deviations $X - \bar X$ and their sum, say for $21$ the deviation shall be $(21 - 23.583333) = -2.583333$ , once you find all the deviations and add them it sums up to $0$
Similarly the sum of squared deviations $\sum(X - \bar X)^2$, again for $21$, $(21 - 23.583333)^2 = 6.41776$
The sum of all squared deviations rounded to the nearest hundredth is equal to $202.90$

Comment: The sum of the deviations is zero for all datasets (can be easily proven with algebra). When your calculator says that the answer is something like $10^{-14}$, it's a rounding error.

Comment: Here's the proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Deviations_from_Mean